# Cross-platform Download Manager for Windows and Fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, ftp, http, download-manager

I'm looking for a software that can be used for downloading files in different Internet Protocols (HTTP, HTTPS, FTP).
The software must be able to continue downloads even if the computer has been restarted.
I currently use BitComet for Windows only. I'm wondering if there's a Universal Download Manager that I can use for both Windows and Fedora that can continue stopped downloads. Is there any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try JDownloader?

```
http://jdownloader.org/home/index
```

Its free, its open and it is java-based so you can run it on either system.

Comment: I think it's great because of Java but it has adware according to wiki. Maybe I'll stick to the browser.

Comment: I see no ads in jdownloader.

Comment: Check the Adware column of this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_download_managers) for JDownloader. Then this is [page](http://www.techsupportall.com/remove-start-mysearchdial-com-removal-help/) for the kind of adware that may be installed.

Comment: I see, you sure now, that you can use jdownloader just by downloading the java files? You don't need the windows installer to get it up an running.